# Can't figure out how to get my attempt to make a digital clock to keep time

Tags: java

So my assignment (surprise, homework!) is to make a GUI that represents a digital clock with two lines. The first line is the clock itself (hh:mm aa), and the second line gives the date as scrolling text (EEEE - MMMM dd, yyyy). I've managed to get all of that to show up, but I can't figure out how to get my date to update with my computer's clock - meaning I run it at 1:47 PM, and it never changes to 1:48 PM. I've been reading around a bit, and it seems like the answer to my problem is to use a Thread and have it `try{Thread.sleep(1000)}` or something along those lines, but after a few hours of experimentation, I can't figure out how to apply it to what I have:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class InnerClasses extends JFrame {
public InnerClasses() {
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    add(new TimeMessagePanel());
    add(new DateMessagePanel());
}

/** Main method */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test frame = new Test();
    frame.setTitle("Clock");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(280, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

static class TimeMessagePanel extends JPanel {
    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
    Date time = new Date();
    private String timeOutput = timeFormat.format(time); 
    private int xCoordinate = 105;
    private int yCoordinate = 20;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(timeOutput, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

static class DateMessagePanel extends JPanel {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE - MMMM dd, yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    private String dateOutput = dateFormat.format(date); 
    private int xCoordinate = 0;
    private int yCoordinate = 20;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(250, new TimerListener());

    public DateMessagePanel() {
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (xCoordinate > getWidth() - 50) {
            xCoordinate = -50;
        }
        xCoordinate += 5;
        g.drawString(dateOutput, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) move all computing logic (what IS computing logic: get new Date instance, format it, etc, what ISNT computing logic: add panel to layout, set jframe visible, etc.) to `recompute()` method

2) call

```
recompute();
repaint();
```

in your TimerListener

Comment: Let's see if I can get this to show up right...

`public void recompute(){
   Date newDate = new Date();
   timeOutput = timeFormat.format(newDate);
  }`

Well, I can't seem to get it to jump lines here, but that's what I ended up doing (and then calling it in the TimeListener as you said), and it appears to work. So unless you feel I missed something important that I didn't notice, I think that did it - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You already have a Timer which does repainting, in order to paint the new time you'll need to make sure you update your time `String` to the new time.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine you mean something similar to answer proposed below. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you can split your problem in to 3 parts.

1. A Label that displays the given time
2. A component that scrolls whatever text has been given to it (you can find a few options for this as well). This can mean that you run a thread specifically for doing the animation bits.
3. A background thread (make sure that you set it as a daemon thread) that updates the "data" for the above two components.

To your background thread, pass the instances of 1 & 2. You seemed to have figured out the "sleep" part, so now you just need to update the text data on the instances.

Also, ensure that any data updates (if you plan on updating the content of the Swing component directly) are performed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

HTH

Comment: I went ahead and used the above answer because it seemed the easiest to integrate into my existing code, but in the interest of learning, I'd like to try and understand your suggestion as well. For step 2, are you saying to put `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` and what's inside of it into a thread? Because I believe I attempted that earlier and got a compiler error.

Comment: The paintComponent() is still part of the component itself. The thread, or a Timer, is used to modify the content that needs to be painted and then invokes repaint. This modification could be transposition of text or probably preparing an image raster ([][]  pixel array) that will be used for painting. Once the modification is done, you call repaint() on the component.